# Creating a new editor.tokenColorCustomizations color Scope

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration

I was changing the colors of the VS Code UI using `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`, when I noticed that some elements share the same scopes *(which results in the scopes sharing the same color no matter what).*

What I would like to know, is if there is a way to create a new scope, and asign a specific keyword to it?

For example, I would like to add a customized `local` scope for **"Lua"**.

Here's an example of "local" and "nil" sharing the same scopes:

[local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT4Bf.jpg)
[nil](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i84Lr.jpg)

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Grammar Contribution

What you want to do is **Contribute a Grammar** using, VSCode provided, **contribution points**. The grammar contribution point is:  **`contributes.grammars`**

Contribution points are part of the **VS-Code Extension Manifest**.
The VS-Code Extension Manifest is a `package.json` located in the Root Directory of a VS-Code Extension, or Theme. You cannot contribute Grammars from a `./.vscode/settings.json` file.

---

### Defining a Grammar in the Extension Manifest

The type of contribution you will be making in this case looks like:

###### `"grammars": []`

###### Here's an Example of a Grammar Being Defined in a VS-Code Extension's Manifest

---

```
    /* 
      Grammars are defined in the Extension Manifest (package.json), 
      inside of the contributions property.  
    */

{
  "name": "language-latex",
  "description": "LaTex Language Support",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "publisher": "someone",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "0.10.x"
  },
  "categories": ["Programming Languages", "Snippets"],
  "contributes": {
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "latex",
        "aliases": ["LaTeX", "latex"],
        "extensions": [".tex"]
      }
    ],
    "grammars": [
      {
        "language": "latex",
        "scopeName": "text.tex.latex",
        "path": "./syntaxes/latex.tmLanguage.json"
      }
    ],
    "snippets": [
      {
        "language": "latex",
        "path": "./snippets/snippets.json"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

###### Originally authored as part of a contribution example @ VSCode's URL: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#combining-extension-contributions

---

Notice how the Language is defined in the Manifest? This is because this example is defining the Language Latex. It sounds like you want to contribute a Grammar on top of a per-exsisting language, in that case you probably will not need to define a new language. I posted three links to Official VSCode documentation at the bottom of this answer. You will need to read the three links so you can decide exactly what your extension will need. How your Extension Manifest is filled out will be contingent on the grammar you want to define. This probably sounds complicated, but once you get the hang of it, you will find it is a breeze.

Note: Lots of the Advanced VSCode features, like themes, extensions, contributions, tasks, configuring a debugger (things you can't just set a boolean value for in the `settings.json` file), use the same type of methods for using the features. For example, to create a theme, you also contribute the theme, which means once you learn how to contribute a grammar, you will know how to create a theme as well. Visit the contribution Link below to learn more (there's approx 20 different contribution types to read about).

As far as the Grammars section goes, you will need to provide 3 specific values, by assigning them each to the right property:

1. **`grammars.language`** property
2. **`grammars.scopeName`** property
3. **`grammars.pathname`** property

#### The path will use a json file that looks like this:

###### `"./syntaxes/<Your-language>.tmLanguage.json"`

It is a TextMate file converted to a JSON format, and can be located in your VSCode's file, or in the VSCode repository (search through the VSCode repository. It should popup as you are typing it.)

###### Here is a Link to the [VSCode Repository](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode)

---

###### [For more information about Grammar Contributions visit this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#grammar-example](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#grammar-example)

---

###### [For more information about Contributions in general visit this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points)

---

###### [For more information about the VSCode Extension Manifest visit this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#combining-extension-contributions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest#combining-extension-contributions)

---

Any questions regarding this answer, should be asked in the comments section that belongs to this answer.

(Will edit & delete this line, and the line above June 21st @ 11:59pm UTC)